# Hive: Merging Configuration Settings not working

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, orc, hive-configuration

On Hive 2.2.0, I am filling an orc table from another source table of size 1.34 GB, using the query

```
INSERT INTO TABLE TableOrc SELECT * FROM Table; ---- (1)
```

The query creates TableORC table with 6 orc files, which are much smaller than the block size of 256MB.

```
-- FolderList1
-rwxr-xr-x  user1   supergroup  65.01 MB    1/1/2016, 10:14:21 AM   1   256 MB  000000_0
-rwxr-xr-x  user1   supergroup  67.48 MB    1/1/2016, 10:14:55 AM   1   256 MB  000001_0
-rwxr-xr-x  user1   supergroup  66.3 MB     1/1/2016, 10:15:18 AM   1   256 MB  000002_0
-rwxr-xr-x  user1   supergroup  63.83 MB    1/1/2016, 10:15:41 AM   1   256 MB  000003_0
-rwxr-xr-x  user1   supergroup  69.11 MB    1/1/2016, 10:15:57 AM   1   256 MB  000004_0
-rwxr-xr-x  user1   supergroup  23.83 MB    1/1/2016, 10:16:02 AM   1   256 MB  000005_0
```

To potentially remove this, the configurations below is used as suggested by multiple other stackoverflow users and TableORC is truncated and query (1) is executed again.

```
SET hive.merge.mapfiles=true;
SET hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;
SET hive.merge.size.per.task=128000000; -- (128MB)
SET hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=128000000; -- (128MB)
```

This time the result is a TableOrc having 3 ORC files and LOGS show 3 additional MR jobs

```
-- FolderList2
 -rwxr-xr-x user1   supergroup  132.49 MB   1/1/2016, 11:47:01 PM   1   256 MB  000000_0
 -rwxr-xr-x user1   supergroup  130.12 MB   1/1/2016, 11:47:02 PM   1   256 MB  000001_0
 -rwxr-xr-x user1   supergroup  92.93 MB    1/1/2016, 11:47:03 PM   1   256 MB  000002_0
```

My question is why are the ORC file sizes greater than 128MB when the configuration settings are set to use 128MB (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties)

```
hive.merge.size.per.task
Default Value: 256000000
Added In: Hive 0.4.0
Size of merged files at the end of the job.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initial average file size is smaller than `hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize`, that is why merge task started to merge them.
First two files merged 65.01 MB + 67.48 MB = 132.49 MB this is bigger than `hive.merge.size.per.task` that is why merge task will stop to merge this resulted file with more files. It will not be splitted to be exactly 128M. The method it works is quite simple.