# Reducing mappers and reducers for a simple query on a very large table/view in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, query-optimization, apache-tez

We have a simple query running on a table/view which is approx of size 5 TB. We are performing ETL and finally adding the data to the core table by adding a partition.

But as the data we are processing is huge, the query spawns 4000+ mappers and 1000+ reducers. Query also runs for 40+ mins.

How can I improve /reduce resource utilization?

Query:

```
insert overwrite table dss.prblm_mtrc partition (LOAD_DT) select *, '2019-01-02' as LOAD_DT from dss.v_prblm_mtrc_stg_etl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use static partition, in case there are already many partitions in target table, Hive will scan them faster before final load, see also this: [HIVE Dynamic Partitioning tips](https://qubole.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/214885263-HIVE-Dynamic-Partitioning-tips)

```
insert overwrite table dss.prblm_mtrc partition (LOAD_DT='2019-01-02') select * from dss.v_prblm_mtrc_stg_etl
```

If your source table has too many small files, try to reduce them, use [concatenate for orc files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50042837/2700344) or use [merge during loading source table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48303807/2700344)

Use vectorizing, tune mappers and reducers parallelism: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48487306/2700344

```
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = true;
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled = true;
```

All vectorizing settings are [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-Vectorization).

And if you target table contains many already loaded partitions, try to switch off statistics auto gathering, this setting may speed-up loading:

```
set hive.stats.autogather=false;
```

Also if your source table is orc and splits calculation takes too long time, try this setting:

```
hive.exec.orc.split.strategy=BI;
```

More about ORC strategy: [ORC split strategy](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-hive.exec.orc.split.strategy)

Comment: many thanks on all these suggestions.  i will start working on this rightaway and keep you posted on the progress.