# How to set min and max parquet files size in Hive?

Tags: hive, parquet

I have created the external table using parquet in hive using snappy compression. I want to configure the parquet files size created in the target folder. I.e Min file size = 1024B and Max file size = 128MB based on these configurations, no of parquet files should be created. Can anyone please let me know how this can be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: This is related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45266244/2700344 And this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55375261/2700344 And this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48303807/2700344

Comment: @leftjoin Thank you for your reply. Those links were helpful.