# When to set hive parameters during a session?

Tags: hadoop, hive, parameters, hiveql, hive-configuration

I'm new to my role and part of it requires creating/inserting data into both managed and external hive tables. We have a few lines of 'set' parameters that we run at the beginning of a hive session, but I've run into a few cases, where, for example, the files are merged for some partitions (few number of files), but not others (many smaller files), seemingly on random days.

My question is: when is it necessary to enter all of my Hive set parameters? Does it need to be done for every single insert/command/statement I'm running? Or just once at the beginning of the Hive session when I've launched Hive?

These are the standard set parameters we've been using:

```
SET mapred.job.queue.name=yometrics;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=2000;
SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=2000;
SET hive.merge.tezfiles=true;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put configuration in the beginning of the file, it will work for the whole session.

Alternatively you can put common parameters in the separate file `params.hql` and in each script call

`source /local/path/to/the/file/params.hql` in the beginning.

Also you can put them in the `hive-site.xml`

Also you can use bootstrap for the same if you are on Qubole/AWS: https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/hive/bootstrap-script.html

Comment: thank you - can you clarify what a 'session' entails? Is it only running a single INSERT statement, for example? Is that a single session? If I were to run the set parameters when I initialize Hive, and say, run 10 INSERT statements separately, do I need to run the set statements every single time? Or only once at the very beginning?

Comment: @phenderbender  Session it is one hive invocation with a script file (-f option), which can include other files using SOURCE command or inline ( -e option). All the whole script is a single session. For particular statements you can override settings in the same script before statement.

Comment: @phenderbender Have a look at this answer about merge: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48303807/2700344 and this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45266244/2700344

Comment: thank you @leftjoin  Do you know whether SET hive.merge.tezfiles=true; versus set hive.merge.mapfiles=true; is better for external tables? I just tried running with both of these, and it got my file count down drastically. I'm trying again with just hive.merge.mapfiles=true since adding that seemed to do the trick, but I can't find anything online for which to use on external vs managed

Comment: @phenderbender It does not matter managed or external in this context. hive.merge.mapfiles will work if the job is map-only, no reducer. Force reducer by adding `order by `and you will see.