# How do I control file output size when using Beeline's INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY?

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

I am running many commands like this to export data from hive as CSVs:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/output/database/table/' 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
SELECT * FROM database.table;
```

That command does exactly what I want it to, but I am getting totally random file sizes on the output ranging from 100mb to 500mb. I would like to specify a max file size for it to write out, around 200mb. Is this possible?

Comment: Try merging settings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48303807/2700344 and also you can try to control the number of files https://stackoverflow.com/a/55375261/2700344

Comment: Hmm, so I can't predict the number of files it should be because I am running this on way too many tables. Unless I am not understanding merging, I don't thing it will help me in this situation because the files are larger than my target, not smaller.

Comment: See second link in my first comment, bytes.per.reducer allows to limit the MAX file size. And if the job is running as map-only,trigger the reducer step by adding something like `distribute by <evenly distributed key>`

Comment: And I'm not sure will merge work in combination with bytes.per.reducer, this is worth trying